# How to export data as csv format from Druid that already exits in the Druid?

Tags: export, datasource, druid

I loaded data (almost 1-billion row data) from hdfs (Hadoop) to  Apache Druid. Now, I am trying to export this data set as a CSV to my local. Is there any way to do this in Druid?

There is a download icon on the druid SQL. However, when you click it, it allows you to download the data up to which page you are on. I have soo many pages, so I cannot go through all pages to download all data.

Comment: If you execute a native scan query (https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/querying/scan-query.html) with the `resultFormat` set to `compactedList`, the result in the events property are as close to csv as it gets. With a tool like jq it should be relatively easy to convert the data to csv.

Comment: I am not executing a native scan query. What I am trying to do is also get an export of the result of my query.

Comment: Are you executing the query from the command line? Or in your code? From the command line you should be able to convert the result to csv with a tool like `jq`.

Answer (score 1):

You can `POST` a SQL query to the Query API and provide a `resultFormat` in your `POST` of `csv`.

https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/querying/sql.html#responses